# show activity after click on notification

Tags: android, notifications, resume

Im trying to reactivate my app after user clicked on the notification. I've found some examples and explanations but nothing worked for me. Please see my code below. The user can hide the app while it's running so the notification is informing about the running process. After it's finished or while it's running, I want the user to be able to show the app by clicking on the notification. How can I do that in this case? What's working now: The notification with a progress bar while process running. But nothing happens on click it.

```
    private void bgTasksStarter(final String doThis, final String thisFileName, final String thisCompPass, final String thisTestStr) {


    String sOut = "";
    switch(doThis) {
        case doEncrypt:
            sOut = lng.encryption;
            break;

        case doDecrypt:
            sOut = lng.decryption;
            break;
    }

    final String fsOut = sOut;

    final int id = 1;

    final NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    final Builder mBuilder;

    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(thisFileName)
        .setContentText(fsOut + " " + lng.isRunning)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    bgTasks = new BgTasks();
                    bgTasks.execute(doThis, thisFileName, thisCompPass, thisTestStr);

                    mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
                    mNotifyManager.cancel(id);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

                    while (busy) {

                        try {
                                Thread.sleep(1*1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                Log.d("xxx", "sleep failure");
                            }
                    }
                        mBuilder.setContentText(fsOut + " " + lng.isFinished)
                            .setProgress(0,0,false);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

                }
            }
        ).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the setContentIntent method that will trigger the pending intent when you click on the notification.

```
Intent launcher = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
launcher.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launcher, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(launcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add an intent through pendingIntent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, desiredClass.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Notice the flag FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and check if it is the right one for your case.

Comment: Two men, one answer! :) Thanks a lot! Unfortunatelly, it's possible to accept only one. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not here for recognition but to help so I'm glad.